# Seeing output from Kotlin error() function in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm throwing exceptions via `error("my error message")` in my Kotlin code. How can I see `"my error message"` when the error happens?

I'm not seeing it in Android Studio's Logcat console tab or Run console tab. Being able to see `"my error message"` when the error is hit would make debugging my Android app a lot easier.

Comment: Are you seeing the stack trace at all? It should be in both tabs you mentioned, but maybe there's a filter blocking it.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing a stack trace.

Comment: The `error()` function throws an IllegalStateException, so the logged stack trace should have an IllegalStateException at the top of the stack trace with your message. What's showing at the top of your stack trace?

Comment: I think it was just a generic "uncaught exception" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error(msg: Any)` kotlin function only throws an exception and does not log it. Unless your app crashes the logs will not be shown in logcat.

What you can do is create your own function which both throws and logs:

```
fun throwAndLogError(tag: String, message: String) {
    Log.e(tag, message)
    error(message)
}
```

Comment: By default, an uncaught exception is logged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the message directly. something like this

```
try {
    throw Error("my error message")
    // or other code that potentially throw an error
} catch (exception: Exception) {
    println(exception.message)
}
```